# Whats wrong with this Regular Expression? (2)

Tags: java, android, regex

Why wont this RegEx give me any results?!?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\S*\\s)\\S*est\\S*($|\\s\\S*)"); //
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is my test string");
if(m.matches())
   Log.d("TRACE", "result " + m.group());
```

I have testet the Pattern in [gskinners RegExr](http://regexr.com?36jo5) where it works fine, then i ecaped the right terms i think but it never gives me any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) wants to match the whole string. If you want to match part of the string, use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\S*\\s)\\S*est\\S*($|\\s\\S*)"); //
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is my test string");
if(m.find())
   Log.d("TRACE", "result " + m.group());
```

Comment: Thx, what a stupid mistake!I realy have my troubles with RegEx. But it only gives me the first "find" back! What would i have to change to let it find every result?!? for ex. in "this is my test string, another test string" it should return "my test string" & "another test string"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `+` or a `*` sign after first and last groups, since they may be repeated multiple times:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\S*\\s)+\\S*est\\S*($|\\s\\S*)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is my test string");
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: this just gives me the whole string back!

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r If you want the groups, you must use `group(int index)`. [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) specify that `group()` always returns the entire string matched by the previous match. In this case, the regex is matching the full string so `group()` will return it as well.